# Spring HATEOAS wrong self link with linked resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.3, Spring Data REST, Spring HATEOAS.
My domain model is quite structured but lately I found a strange behaviour in self links.

I'm going to show part of the model to point out the problem, removing useless part:

**EyeExam:**

```
@EntityListeners(value = EyeExamListener.class)
public class EyeExam extends AbstractEntity {

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", updatable = false)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ContactUriDeserializer.class)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Contact contact;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private Instant date;
```

**Contact:**

```
@EntityListeners({ContactListener.class})
public class Contact extends AbstractEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'CUSTOMER'")
    private ContactType type = ContactType.CUSTOMER;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'NATURAL_PERSON'")
    private PersonType personType = PersonType.NATURAL_PERSON;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String companyName;
```

This is **ContactRepository**:

```
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long> {
 ....
 ....
}
```

When I retrieve a specific EyeExam resource (https://myserver.com/api/v1/eyeExams/13) Spring returns:

```
  {
  "sid" : "f16d6e45-477f-11e9-898e-9d6f4f2f5990",
  "createdBy" : "system",
  "createdDate" : "2017-05-31T17:38:00Z",
  "lastModifiedDate" : null,
  "lastModifiedBy" : null,
  "createdByName" : "System",
  "lastModifiedByName" : null,
  "date" : "2017-05-31T00:00:00Z",

  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/eyeExams/13"
    },
    "eyeExam" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/eyeExams/13{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "supplyTypes" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/eyeExams/13/supplyTypes"
    },
    "changeStatus" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/eyeExams/13/changeStatus?status=%7Bstatus%7D"
    },
    "contact" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/eyeExams/13/contact{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "store" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/eyeExams/13/store{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I get a link to linked resource Contact. That's ok. Now I get the resource https://myserver.com/api/v1/eyeExams/13/contact and Spring replies:

```
{
  "sid" : "4c2ba300-477e-11e9-898e-9d6f4f2f5990",
  "createdBy" : "system",
  "createdDate" : "2018-11-01T09:00:00Z",
  "lastModifiedDate" : null,
  "lastModifiedBy" : null,
  "createdByName" : "System",
  "lastModifiedByName" : null,
  "type" : "CUSTOMER",
  "personType" : "NATURAL_PERSON",
  "firstName" : "John",
  "lastName" : "Smith",
  "companyName" : null,  
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contact/22352"
    },
    "contact" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contact/22352{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "notes" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contacts/22352/notes"
    },
    "auditLogs" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contacts/22352/auditLogs"
    },
    "media" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contacts/22352/media"
    },
    "privacyAgreements" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contacts/22352/privacyAgreements"
    },
    "eyeExams" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contacts/22352/eyeExams"
    },
    "eyeExamsCount" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contacts/22352/eyeExams/count"
    },
    "documents" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contacts/22352/documents"
    },
    "pendingSalesOrders" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contacts/22352/pendingSalesOrders"
    },
    "lastPurchasedFrames" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contacts/22352/lastPurchasedFrames"
    },
    "store" : {
      "href" : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/contact/22352/store{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  }
}
```

I want point out the self link. It is **wrong**, in fact it should be **https://myserver.com/api/v1/contacts/22352** with the end -s.

I was using some custom ResourceProcessor, but even without them I've the same problem.

Right now I created a workaround in ContactResourceProcessor, rewriting the self link with the right one but I'd like to understand if I'm doing something wrong, if it's a bug or I just missed something.

Comment: What kind of class-level annotations you have on ContactRepository interface?

Comment: @Selindek I added the repository in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bug, but try this workaround:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path="contacts")
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long> {
 ....
 ....
}
```

Comment: I tried but I doesn't work. I had to rewrite the self link in the ResourceProcessor